# Execute function only by correct series of keys

Tags: javascript, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm not exactly into this professionally, but just out of curiosity since only VERY recently. Thus I only have the most basic OF basic knowledge.

My current experiment is this; can you program a series of keys, to execute a specific function, and only in the correct order? I'm saying like a game combo (ie: the famous Konami Code easter egg, consisting of '↑', '↑', '↓', '↓', '←', '→', '←', '→', 'B', 'A', and 'Start')

If, say, I use 'onkeydown' to do this, it only registers that one key, not taking into regard any keys pressed earlier or after (or so I believe). If not, I would have to somehow record what came before and... waaaay out of my little fishies league.

Is there a way to do such a thing, hopefully simpler and easier? Please don't expect me to know much, and please no JQuery or another such js library :D usage.

Could you script in the Konami Code as an example? The js char codes for this pattern  would be 38 38 40 40 37 39 37 39 66 65 13, replacing the Nintendo 'Start' with 'Enter' key.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by Konami Code, but here's a simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/KhK2j/ . It could definitely be improved/organized better and cleaned up a little, but it works for now :)

Comment: @lan that looks like what he wants :)

Comment: @Ian it works perfectly fine, thanks! The unofficially accepted answer I guess. But just one little thing... can a timer be set to complete the code once it has begun? (Say, when ↑ is pressed, 10 more seconds for the whole code to be completed or auto reset? Or maybe even 2 seconds limit to press the next key in the series or an auto reset?)

Comment: @Terrornado Well, here's how I'd more fully implement (still not exactly how I'd do it) your first question at least: http://jsfiddle.net/pP49S/ . You can change `finishTimerLength` to be how many milliseconds you want to wait for it to timeout

Comment: Thanks again! Also, can the correct sequence be obfuscated or something and hidden from view to anybody who reads the source script (at least beginners)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working example, if you mess up, you can simply restart the sequence and it will forgive you. Also, if you want a different combination, just change "keys".

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
var keys=[38,38,40,40,37,39,37,39,66,65];
var buff=[];
function collect(e){
  buff.push(e.keyCode);
  if(buff.length>keys.length){
    buff=buff.splice(1);
  }
  if(keys==buff.toString()){ 
    alert("Let's Play!");
  }
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<DIV contenteditable=true onkeydown="collect(event)">Click here to accept keystrokes</DIV>
</body>
</html>
```

I put the key capture in a DIV, but you can add it to the document.body instead and it will listen everywhere on the page.

Comment: How do you add this to the document.body and not just a section of the page?

Comment: just put the onkeydown event in the <body> tag instead of the <DIV> tag.

Answer (score 1):

Just listen for keys and compare against something :

```
var konami = [38,38,40,40,37,39,37,39,66,65],
    pushed = [];

document.onkeyup = function(e) {
    pushed.push(e.which);

    for (var i=0; i<pushed.length; i++) {
        if (pushed[i] != konami[i]) pushed = [];
    }

    if (pushed.length == konami.length) alert('konami code');
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/N5jQM/3/)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, so I take it the 'pushed' is being compared against 'konami'? And that 'if (pushed.length == konami.length) alert('konami code');' can be edited to 'if (pushed.length == konami.length) { blah blah blah some script I want to happen when konami code is entered } ?